# How can I stop [Neo]Vim from tracking parens in certain situations?

Tags: delimiter-matching

Whenever I have to do things like this: `closeparens = ")]}"` or `/[)\]}]/` it messes up the parenthesis tracking of the whole file. I could mitigate this with comments:

```
# complement to ([{ (this is not at all to help with vim's highlighting)
local closeparens="}])"


# don't mind me, just gonna put these here: (((
case $X in
   a) echo 1 ;;
   b) echo 2 ;;
   c) echo 3 ;;
esac
```

But I'd rather not modify my code because of my text editor.

How would I go about configuring this?
No need for an easy answer, if I have to modify the gosh darned source code of vim I will. Just any sort of pointer on where to start would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [matchit-zip](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/matchit-zip)

> The matchit.vim script allows you to configure % to match more than just single characters.  You can match words and even regular expressions. **Also, matching treats strings and comments (as recognized by the syntax highlighting mechanism) intelligently.**

also:

> Since vim 6.0, matchit.vim has been included in the standard vim distribution, under the macros/ directory

but IMO it's easier to install the plugin linked above.

Comment: I was already in the process of cooking up my own solution, but this is probably the one that is going to be the most useful for most people. I am going to see how convoluted/geared too much towards my own workflow this gets, and if it's too much I will accept your answer (prolly gonna happen).

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I was in the middle of implementing my solution, and as soon as a SQL database came into the mix I immediately decided to come here and accept your answer ;P